# How can a remote-controlled (wall) light switch operate without a power source?

Tags: switches, ac, light

A few days ago, i bought [this](http://www.ebay.de/itm/1-Gang-Touch-Lichtschalter-Glas-Unterputz-Funk-Wandschalter-Taster-Fernbedienung-/281638774468?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_77&hash=item4192faa6c4) remote-conrolled light switch. When installing it, i wondered why i had only two lines to connect (the one going to AC power and the one to the lamp); i thought i needed a ground connection as well to provide power to the electronics.

[image: Back side with AC connection][image: Front side with electronics]

However, the switch works after connecting only two lines (L to AC and L2 to the lamp); it has some electronics inside, and does not seem to contain a battery. Where does it get the power from it needs for the electronics?

Comment: Well, guess where the line that goes through the lamp ends...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is a complete circuit; hot side of the line through the switch then through the lamp and back to the ground side of the line.

When the lamp is supposed to be "off", the electronics "steals" just enough current to power itself, but not enough to light the lamp.  When the lamp is on, again the switch steals just enough power to run itself.

This technique has been around a long time, it used to be used to provided illuminated light switches (typically using a NE-2 neon lamp), which would glow when the lamp is off.

This only works if current can be drawn through the lamp when the lamp s off.   Obviously this works fine for conventional incandescent lamps.  I would guess it doesn't work for CFL's.  There is probably a list on the instructions.

Comment: I thought those illuminated light switches, that don't require a neutral, don't use the bulb to complete the circuit but rather leak current from live to ground.

Comment: @DanD.: all I know have L in L out, no GND

Comment: @DanD. In other countries where the entire house is powered through an earth-leakage circuit-breaker (aka GFCI) and not just selected sockets, leaking any current to ground would be a problem and cause the breaker to trip.